# Does jest have something like aroundEach?

Tags: jestjs

Does the testing library jest have something like `aroundEach` that's present in other testing libraries? I'm not sure if it's just not there or I'm searching with the wrong thing. I'm referring to something that would allow me to write code like this:

```
aroundEach(test => {
  console.log("Printed before each test")
  test() // Runs the actual test
  console.log("Printed after each test")
})
```

For example, this is necessary to be able to write code that uses cls-hooked to run the test with a particular context. For example:

```
import {createNamespace} from "cls-hooked"

aroundEach(test => {
  let context = createNamespace("context")
  context.run(() => {
    context.set("a_number", 123456)
    test() // Runs the actual test
  })
})
```

Here's an example on how to do it with Ruby MiniTest: https://github.com/jeremyevans/minitest-hooks#around-hooks-

Here's a tutorial on how it's done with Rspec in Ruby: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/03/24/using-the-rspec-around-hook/

In an attempt to make this work, I tried creating my own function, `wrappedTest` to replace (and wrap) `test`, like this:

```
function wrappedTest(name: string, fn?: ProvidesCallback, timeout?: number) {
  let wrappedFn = fn
  if (fn) {
    wrappedFn = (done) => {
      console.log("Before the test")
      fn(done)
      console.log("After the test")
    }
  }
  test(name, wrappedFn, timeout)
}
```

and then for my test, I would just use `wrappedTest` instead of `test`:

```
wrappedTest("Example test", async () => {
  console.log("this is the actual test")
})
```

Unfortunately, it fails with this error:

```
  console.log src/entity/User.test.ts:24
    Before the test

  console.log src/entity/User.test.ts:33
    this is the actual test

  console.log src/entity/User.test.ts:26
    After the test


: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
```

I tried adding `await` but it made no difference:

```
function wrappedTest(name: string, fn?: ProvidesCallback, timeout?: number) {
  let wrappedFn = fn
  if (fn) {
    wrappedFn = async (done) => {
      console.log("Before the test")
      await fn(done)
      console.log("After the test")
    }
  }
  test(name, wrappedFn, timeout)
}
```

If I call `done` in my actual test, like this:

```
wrappedTest("Example test", async (done) => {
  console.log("this is the actual test")
  done()
})
```

it works, but it's not necessary when I'm using `test` so I don't understand why it's necessary when using `wrappedTest`.

Oh... and this whole approach may be completely wrong anyway.

Comment: Do you mean beforeEach and afterEach?

Comment: @sdgluck: no, those don't allow you to wrap the test, only run before or after.

Comment: This seems like XY problem. What exactly are you trying to do that cannot be achieved with before/afterEach? What's the deal with doSomething? And no, there's no such thing in Jest because it's likely not needed.

Comment: @EstusFlask: as I said in the question, it runs the code in the callback inside a database transaction.

Comment: Most testing frameworks provide for some sort of setup and teardown, which is all you're doing in your aroundEach.  Despite your insistence on something that looks like a "wrapper," `beforeEach` and `afterEach` ought to fit this bill nicely.

Comment: Is `transaction` some known DB API? In case you have real code problem, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . In case there's promise API for a lib you use, use it. Otherwise it's more convenient to convert callback-based API to in Jest, then it becomes very straightforward with async..await: `let manager; beforeEach(async () => { manager = await new Promise(resolve => connection.transaction(resolve)) }`, etc. A way it should be done depends on how async errors are handled in this API because it doesn't seem to use error-first callbacks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: how would you express having cls-hook namespace defined on the test being run by only using `beforeEach` and `afterEach`? I don't think it's possible, happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: @EstusFlask: it's my own code that uses TypeORM on the back, but let me simplify the example so we have less distractions.

Comment: There, no more mention of any connection, just cls-hooked.

Comment: So this is primarily Jest vs CLS at this point. Since shoving everything inside `run` callback isn't an option in Jest because you can't wrap several beforeEach, etc blocks with it, I expect it to be solved in some another way. I didn't use CLS a lot, it's likely something like https://github.com/Jeff-Lewis/cls-hooked/issues/17#issuecomment-510168720 . It's funny the relevant parts are undocumented, https://github.com/Jeff-Lewis/cls-hooked/issues/44  As for TypeORM, it supports promises by design, I wouldn't expect any problems with that part.

Comment: I don't understand how supporting promises by design solves this problem.

Comment: @pupeno Promise allows to get rid of callback hell in tests, that's the idea. You should not use `done` with `async` in Jest, it's either one or another. `done` is low level, when you forget to call it, a test times out. Any way, I'm not sure that what you're trying with wrappedTest can help your original issue with `run`.

Comment: @EstusFlask: I understand the relationship between async and promise, what I don't understand is how that allows you to solve the problem of transaction working by callback here: https://typeorm.io/#/transactions (ignore the fact that the manager is an argument, I workarounded that by using cls-hooked).

Comment: The reference you linked already uses promises with async..await, this can be translated as is to Jest. This really depends on what you're trying to do at this point. You can separate them between `async` `before/afterEach` and `it`. Or do this inside single `it` with `async` and `try..finally`, similarly to https://typeorm.io/#/transactions/using-queryrunner-to-create-and-control-state-of-single-database-connection , this would be closer to what you wanted `aroundEach` for. Consider re-asking a question that addresses your problem with TypeORM and Jest if you have a specific one.